# Python google sheets, for loop exiting after one loop

Tags: python, for-loop, google-sheets

I have a simple script which read google sheets.
It works perfectly fine, if there are more than one rows in the sheet.
But, If the sheet has only one row, the for loop exists after one loop.
I want the loop to come back and display the input text even if there is one row in the sheet.

```
# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=sheetID,
                            range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
#print(values)

if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:

    for row in values:

        x = input('Please type\n "r" for (r)egex check \n "n" for (n)etwork check \n ')

        if x == 'r' or x == 'R':
            for row in values:
                hostname = row[0]
                check_reg(hostname)           


        elif x == 'n' or x=='N':
            for row in values:

                network = row[4]
                netCmd = 'ipaddr'
                print('\n network',network)
                subprocess.call(netCmd, shell=True)

        elif x=='x' or x=='X':
                break

        else:
            print('Only n,x,r values accepted.')
```

Comment: Are you sure you need both that outer `for row in values:` as well as the two inner `for row in values:`? I would think the outer one is extraneous, or should be a `while input("blabla").lower() in ["r", "n", "x"]:`

Comment: thanks Dan! that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to have an infinite loop until you break out of it. Also in the current solution you will not stay in this loop, even if you have multiple rows.

A solution could look like this:

```
# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=sheetID,
                            range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
#print(values)

if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:

    while True:

        x = input('Please type\n "r" for (r)egex check \n "n" for (n)etwork check \n ')

        if x == 'r' or x == 'R':
            for row in values:
                hostname = row[0]
                check_reg(hostname)           


        elif x == 'n' or x=='N':
            for row in values:
                network = row[4]
                netCmd = 'ipaddr'
                print('\n network',network)
                subprocess.call(netCmd, shell=True)

        elif x=='x' or x=='X':
            break

        else:
            print('Only n,x,r values accepted.')
```

Comment: instead of `while True`, how about `while input(prompt).lower() not in ["r", "n", "x"]:`

Answer (score 2):

Use `IF` statement and then going to the loop only if the sheet has more than 1 line seems to work.

Mind you, the `IF` statement should be before entering the the `for loop` but after checking whether the sheet is empty.